# How to mock service in unit test

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

For example, I have this method in FileServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class FileServiceImpl implements FileService {

private final ExecutorService executorService;
private final UploadsService uploadsService;
private final CandidatesService candidatesService;

@Autowired
public FileServiceImpl(ExecutorService executorService, UploadsService uploadsService, CandidatesService candidatesService) {
    this.executorService = executorService;
    this.uploadsService = uploadsService;
    this.candidatesService = candidatesService;
}

@Override
public Upload uploadFile(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    String filename = file.getOriginalFilename();
    if (!filename.endsWith(".xlsx")) {
        throw new IOException("File format is not .xlsx");
    }

    Upload upload = new Upload(UploadStatus.IN_PROGRESS, LocalDateTime.now(), filename);
    uploadsService.saveUpload(upload);

    executorService.execute(new XLSXAsyncImporter(upload, file.getInputStream(), uploadsService, candidatesService));

    return upload;
    }
}
```

How I need to write unit test? I've started to write this:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class FileServiceImplTest {

@Mock
private ExecutorService executorService;

@Mock
private UploadsService uploadsService;

@Mock
private CandidatesService candidatesService;

private FileServiceImpl fileService;

private Upload upload;
private MockMultipartFile file1, file2;

@BeforeEach
public void setUp() {
    fileService = new FileServiceImpl(executorService, uploadsService, candidatesService);

    upload = new Upload(UploadStatus.DONE, LocalDateTime.of(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0), "filename");
    file1 = new MockMultipartFile("filename 1", "filename.xlsx", "multipart/form-data", "".getBytes());
    file2 = new MockMultipartFile("filename 2", "", "multipart/form-data", "".getBytes());
}
```

I wanna to write two tests: service method done & service method throws IOException.
Please, could you help write me test methods? I covered with tests more simple other services. But I'm confused what I need to do with this one.

Comment: To start: you shouldn't mock `ExecutorService`.  Use a real one.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman, thanks for your advice. But why? Won't I have to use `executorService.execute` check in test method? Can you explain why I shouldn't mock it? I'd like to understand how correctly write tests.

Comment: No, why would you?  It's an implementation detail.  You should use real types in tests wherever possible, and only use mocks for things that would be expensive to set up.

Comment: That's cause there are this type of tests in our team at this time, so I need to do this way - this is my task

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as you thought, it is not necessary to use real `ExecutorService`.

The point here is to test the upload functionality. If this functionality uses an external service, object or whatever, you should mock this third part piece of software. The focus is always your code, your functionality.

Going back to your code I'd test three aspects:

1. the file validation
2. the call to the uploadservice
3. the submit to the executor service